# Powershell replacing $var in a string with $var value

Tags: powershell

Simple enough question but I cant figure this out. I have a string with a variable name in it, and I want to replace the variable with its value. i.e.

```
PS > $test = "Hello `$name"
PS > $test
Hello $name
PS > $name = "Tizz"
PS > $name
Tizz
```

I cannot change the values of $test or $name. I need a new variable with the replaced value (I want $testTizz to have the string value "Hello Tizz"). So logically I tried this and failed

```
PS > $testTizz = $test -replace "`$name", $name
PS > $testTizz
Hello $name
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take out the backquote.  Variables between double quotes will be interpreted.

```
$name = "Tizz"
"Hello $name"

Hello Tizz
```

A backquote before the $ escapes it.

```
"Hello `$name"

Hello $name
```

I don't understand why you are doing this, but this works, replacing the literal '$name', since the backquote escapes the dollarsign.  Also $ is a regex expression and needs to be backslashed.  %name% would be a variable in cmd, not in powershell.

```
$test -replace '\$name', $name

Hello Tizz
```

Comment: I'd give you an upvote but then you wouldn't have `9999` rep anymore..

Comment: Sorry, I cannot change the values of $test or $name. These are from passed in parameters. I just used this as an example. What backquote are you referring to? I want a new string variable with the replaced value.

Comment: I updated my question. This is in a function and I am passed the $test string and cannot change. I can request that this $test variable to be "Hello %name%", then ```$test -replace "%name%", $name``` will work, but that is not the intent here.

Comment: @Paolo Not anymore.

Comment: @js2010 Congrats on the 10k!

Comment: YES! Thank you! ```$test -replace '\$name', $name``` is the answer. I understand % isnt for powershell, but it would work but not what I wanted to do.